# Как подсчитать количество букв в двух словах одинаковой длины, которые стоят на одном и том самом месте на ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер, masm

Как подсчитать количество букв в двух словах одинаковой длины, которые стоят на одном и том самом месте? (masm)
For example:

A**B**CDE**F**

E**B**DFG**F**

Output: 2

Пробовал но не получается :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    mov esi, Word1 ;указатели на строки
    mov edi, Word2
    mov ecx, Length ;длина строк
    xor eax, eax
L1: cmpsb
    jne L2
    inc eax
L2: loop L1 ;результат будет в EAX
```

Comment: Не могу запустить

Comment: можешь написать полностью? Просто нету времени сейчас, сесия, нужно срочно сдать

Comment: https://pastebin.com/9pPHG907